# Regular Expression for replacing newlines

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Just want to know why my regular expression is giving me 2 br tags instead of 1 when the string contains \n\r?

I'm trying to replace \n, \r, \r\n and \n\r with the following:

```
$string="testing \n\r testing2";
$result=preg_replace("/\r?\n|\n?\r/", "<br />", $string);
echo "$result";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best match for `/\r?\n|\n?\r/` on `"\n\r"` is the substring consisting of the first character only (the `\n`). This is because the regex engine tries to find a match for `/\r?\n/` before it starts looking for a match for `/\n?\r/`.* This is always true for `|` matches: a match for the part of the regex before the `|` takes precedence over a match for the regex after it.

And so, having found its first match, it continues from where it left off and discovers that the next character also matches the regex. That's 2 matches, each of which is replaced by a `"<br />"`.

Try doing `/\r\n?|\n\r?/` instead.

*(More precisely, it looks for matches for `/\r?\n/` anchored at the start of the string before searching for matches for `/\n?\r/` anchored at the start; only if these searches fail does it start looking for matches anchored later in the string.)

Comment: Thanks I noticed why the expression was failing shortly after I posted the question. Your tweak on the expression covers all the possible newline combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the native [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function that achieves the same thing

```
$string="testing \n\r testing2";
echo nl2br($string);
```

Comment: I think nl2br adds br tags after the new lines rather than replacing them.

Comment: Just double checked and you are right, but could clean that up with a `str_replace(array("\n","\r"), '', $string);`

Comment: Yea it would be possible doing that but I just wanted to do this through regex rather than str replace. I'm just a bit confused why my regex works fine for \n, \r, \r\n but then applies 2 br tags for \n\r

Comment: The `\n\r` isn't seen as a single value, but is matched by the `\n` then the `\r` and you get 2 `<br>` tags

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the multiline modifier:

```
/\r?\n|\n?\r/ms
```

so:

```
preg_replace("/\r?\n|\n?\r/ms", "<br />", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is performing as expected. Take another look:

```
/\r?\n|\n?\r/
```

It seems you believe that alternation (`|`) should favor the *longer* match, *i.e.* `\n\r` not `\r`, but that's not the case. Alternation matches whatever matches *first*, with left-to-right precedence.

Therefore upon encountering a `\n\r`, the `\n` is matched by `\r?\n` and replaced with `<br />`, and the `\r` is matched by `\n?\r` and replaced again.

What you want instead is

```
/\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n/
```

but I don't think `\r\n` is generally used, so

```
/\n\r?|\r/
```

should be sufficient.